# How to make Play and Pac4j compatible?

Tags: playframework, pac4j

I use Play 2.8 with pac4j. Play 2.8 uses Jackson 2.10, while pac4j-oidc uses Jackson 2.11. 2.10 is therefore evicted and makes Play unhappy:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.10.5 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.10.0 and < 2.11.0
```

I raised an [issue](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/issues/1824) to ask pac4j to downgrade to Jackson 2.10 but they refused (which I can understand).

What other alternative do I have (other than shading)?

Comment: What's depends on Jackson? Play-json?

Comment: Yes, at least play-json

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is to add `exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-databind")` to all pac4j dependencies other than `play-pac4j`.
It is likely to produce binary that crash though...